# How to use fprintf in UEFI

Tags: file, operating-system, printf, osdev, uefi

There is `fprintf` function in `Stdio` library.

But how to use it?

The first argument is `FILE` type.

But I have `EFI_FILE_PROTOCOL* File` which I got from `EFIOpenFile` function. How to map to `FILE` type?

Comment: You can't. There is no such thing. You have to use stdlib ported for UEFI which underneath uses UEFI SHELL protocol to do all the magic. Then you can use C and stdlib exactly the same as it would be in windows or linux.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are hosted environments and freestanding environments.

From the C standard:

> The two forms of conforming implementation are hosted and freestanding. A conforming hosted implementation shall accept any strictly conforming program. A conforming freestanding implementation shall accept any strictly conforming program in which the use of the features specified in the library clause (clause 7) is confined to the contents of the standard headers `<float.h>`, `<iso646.h>`, `<limits.h>`, `<stdalign.h>`, `<stdarg.h>`, `<stdbool.h>`, `<stddef.h>`, `<stdint.h>`, and `<stdnoreturn.h>`. A conforming implementation may have extensions (including additional library functions), provided they do not alter the behavior of any strictly conforming program.

So in a freestanding environment (like the UEFI environment you are describing) the C standard doesn't require the `fprintf()` function to be defined/declared and doesn't require the `FILE` type to be defined either. Therefore you need to code them on your own.